# Where do I fail, trying to adapt Gauss law in 2D?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions

[image: Gauss Law 2D]

So I went through the Khan Academy tutorial on divergence and flux calculations for an area C encircled by a parametric function $s(t)$.

[image: Flux]

Here $C$ will be a circle with a radius $r$, centered by a point charge $+q$. $F$ will be the electric field vector $E(s(t))$, and $n$ will be the normal vector for the point $s(t)$. As electric field lines permeate outwards linearly, they are parallel with the normal vector. Hence $|E|\times|n|\times cos(\theta) = |E|\times1\times1 = |E| = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}$

For sake of calculating $ds$, we will still need a definition of $s(t) = [rcos(t), rsin(t)]$.

$$s'(t) = [-rsin(t), rcos(t)]$$
$$ds = |s'(t)|dt = r*dt$$

So let's bring them all together,

$$\int \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}\times r*dt =$$
$$\int \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\times dt =$$
$$\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r} \int dt$$

We have to take the integral for the time interval $(0, 2\pi)$, a full period of $s(t)$. This will give us the following end result:

$$\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r} \times 2\pi = \frac{q}{2\epsilon_0r}$$

It is okay, except that annoying $r$ at below. What mistake I did here? I can't see. Please help. Also is experimenting with stuff like good for a student? Or should I just stick to my curriculum?

Comment: Hint:  How does the electric field fall off in 2D? Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/582104/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44515/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The original gauss law would be $\frac{q}{2\epsilon_0}$ but we have an extra $r$ here

Comment: Try n-dimensional space, with potential $1/r^m$ (and sphere surface $~r^{n-1}$. It won't work for just any $m$.

Comment: Hmm... So in 2D, $E = q/r \ne kq/r^2$, and this is the mistake? This is weird. I thought same formulas apply

Comment: You need to distinguish two-dimensional space and a three-dimensional space with system homogeneous along one of the dimensions (which confusingly is also referred to sometimes as "two-dimensional").